# Excluding subsection from ToC and keep the references

Tags: cross-referencing, sectioning, table-of-contents

I need to remove my subsection from ToC. I got that part right without any problems by using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex). Thanks!

But I am unable to use `\ref{"label from my subsection"}` for the selected subsection I just removed from my ToC. Well, I can still link it, but I will only get the reference to the section above my subsection.

Example: (My subsection isn't shown in ToC)

```
\section{Hello World!}
\label{sec:hello_world}

\subsection{Goodbye}
\label{sec:goodbye}

\ref{sec:goodbye}
```

--- Latex will return with the result as below ---

**1. Hello World!**

1.1. Goodbye

1

Comment: Don't follow the advice in the link. Rather set `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`.

Comment: The setcounter is better indeed though I still want the toc depht to be unspoiled for all my other sections, subsection etc. 

Is there any way you can apply a specific tocdepth for one section only. I was thinking something like: 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}{References}

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: Removing only a certain subsection from the toc sounds like a bad idea. Any reader will assume an error. If you inform us a bit more about the reasons, maybe someone here will come up with a better idea.

Comment: Removing subsections from TOC are a bad idea since it will confuse the reader. I agree with that. But in my case the subsections are used to define my references from websites and books. I need all my references to be at least \subsubsections{www.stackexchange.com} or above to keep the numbers intact when I use \ref{"%"}. I use lot of these references in my document to point out where the literature is used. 

The question would have been more precise in the first place if I have stated this.

Answer (score 6):

If you want all `\subsection`s to be removed from the ToC, then all you need in your document preamble is

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

which would set the maximum depth of entries in the ToC to 1 (or `\section`).

If you only want selected `\subsections` to be inserted/not in the ToC, then you should use a different technique. The following defines `\stoptocentries` and `\starttocentries`. The former disables inserting content in the ToC by disabling `\addcontentsline`. The latter restores the functionality.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\stoptocentries}{\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}}
\newcommand{\starttocentries}{\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\stoptocentries% Stop adding content to the ToC
\subsection{A subsection}
\starttocentries% Resume adding content to the ToC
\subsection{Another subsection}
\end{document}
```

Of course, usage of `\stoptocentries` also pertains to other sectional units that use `\addcontentsline`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this out of the box with package [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc).

[image: emove sub section]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}

Hello

\subsection{A}

\subsection{B}

\section{Second Section}

\etocsettocdepth.toc {section}
\subsection {EXCLUDE ME}\label{ssec:excluded}
\etocsettocdepth.toc {subsection}

\subsection {D}

Too bad we have excluded subsection \ref{ssec:excluded} from the TOC!


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Werner, 

It is excatly what I want. Though the reader might find the section weird since it is missing in the TOC as Keks Dose pointed out. 

But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see that the above answer completely answers the question, but I [found another method on the LaTeX website](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1309).

If you want to hide all subsections inside the toc, you should set the counter tocdepth to 1:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

But if you only want this to apply to certain (sub)sections, you can change tocdepth inside the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\subsection{One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\subsection{Two}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\subsection{Three}
\end{document}
```

[Minimal worked example can also be found on the LaTeX website](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1309).